# dynamic allocation for an array in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, malloc

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int  *alocare(int *a, int *n)
    {
        printf("Introduceti numarul de elemente din sir");
        scanf("%d", n);
        a = (int*)(malloc(*n*sizeof(int))); //alocam memorie dinamica (in zona Heap) pentru memorarea unui vector in mod dinamic de n elemente
        if (!a)
        {
            printf("Eroare la alocare\n");
            return 0;
        }
        return a;

    }
    void citire(int *a, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("\telem %d\n", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
    }
    void afisare(int *a, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                printf("%d\n", a[i]);

    }
    void main(void)
    {
        int *a, n;
        a=alocare(a, &n);
        citire(a, n);
        afisare(a, n);
        _getch();
    }
```

The error I am getting is

> error C4700: unitialized local variable 'a' used.

How could I initialize variable `a`? And why it  must be initialized? Because I have a allocation function.

Comment: You don't need to pass `a` as a parameter.

Comment: Where do you get that error? To be more specific, in which line?

Comment: in line "a=alocare(a,&n);"

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `a` uninitialized in function call `alocare(a, &n);`. Pointer to dynamically allocated memory can be returned from a function. Remove the parameter `int *a` and declare `a` as local variable in `alocare`:

```
   int  *alocare(int *n)
   {
        printf("Introduceti numarul de elemente din sir");
        scanf("%d", n);
        // Local declaration of pointer a
        int *a = malloc(*n*sizeof(int)); 
        if (!a)
        {
            printf("Eroare la alocare\n");
            return 0;
        }
        return a;
}
```

and make function call as

```
a = alocare(&n);
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Oops! Sorry.

Comment: and...return 0; ...return NULL; should be better, isn't it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Yes. But you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: Props for noting  `a` needs a local declaration in `alocare` now that is has been stripped from the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because of this line

```
 a=alocare(a, &n);
```

in `main()`. Here, the `a` is a local variable with *auto* storage type, which, unless initialized explicitly, contains garbage value. You don't need to pass `a` as parameter. Just collect the return value of `allocare()` into `a`. That will suffice.

Change your function signature

```
  int  *alocare(int *a, int *n)
```

to

```
  int  *alocare(int *n)
```

and your code

```
a=alocare(a, &n);
```

to

```
a=alocare(&n);
```

and in case of `if (!a)`

```
return 0;
```

to

```
return NULL;  //return type is int *
```

or, better

```
exit(-1);
```

If you choose to return `NULL`, in `main()` check `a` against `NULL` to ensure `malloc()` success.

Note: Instead of `void main(void)`, use `int main(void)`. It's better and recommended.

Also, do not cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in this function

```
int  *alocare(int *a, int *n)
{
    printf("Introduceti numarul de elemente din sir");
    scanf("%d", n);
    a = (int*)(malloc(*n*sizeof(int))); //alocam memorie dinamica (in zona Heap) pentru memorarea unui vector in mod dinamic de n elemente
    if (!a)
    {
        printf("Eroare la alocare\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return a;

}
```

the value of parameter `a` is not used. Also any parameter of a function is a local variable of the function. So when you call the function like

```
a=alocare(a, &n);
```

parameter `a` gets indertermined value of argument `a` because the last was not initialized in main.  There is no sense to declare a paremeter if its value is not used.

I would define the function the following way

```
int  alocare( int **a )
{
    int n = 0;

    printf( "Introduceti numarul de elemente din sir: " );
    scanf( "%d", n );

    if ( n <= 0 ) return 0;

    *a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) ); //alocam memorie dinamica (in zona Heap) pentru memorarea unui vector in mod dinamic de n elemente
    if ( !*a )
    {
        printf("Eroare la alocare\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return n;
}
```

and call it like

```
n = alocare( &a );
```

Though it would be better to declare `n` as having type `size_t`

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main shall have return type `int` that is it should be declared like

```
int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```